# Discrepancy in Generic parametric polymorphism

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Foo<T extends Bar>{
    private Class<T> _type;
    public Foo( Class<T> _type ){
        this._type = _type;
    }
    public Collection<T> hypothetical( List<T> items ){ //PROBLEMATIC
        return dostuffWithItems( items );
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Foo<? extends ChildBar> foo = new Foo<ChildBar>( ChildBar.class );
List<ChildBar> items = ( List<ChildBar> ) foo.hypothetical( new ArrayList<ChildBar>() ); //COMPILER ERROR: The method hypothetical(List<capture#2-of ?>) in the type Foo<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<ChildBar>)
```

The compiler would either accept 

casting `List<ChildBar> items` argument to `List<?>` 

or changing the `hypothetical( List<T> items )` signature to either 

a) `hypothetical( List<ChildBar> items )` or 

b) `hypothetical( List<? extends Bar> items )`

However, none of the alternatives assure that the hypothetical method's List items argument T type is the equivalent runtime type of the Foo class T parametric type. I am currently using an extra method to verify the parametric types at the moment. 
Is there a better way within Java generics constructs to achieve this automatically without the extra logic? Or better yet, why can I not declare foo as `Foo<? extends Bar>` and then fill in the actual type parameter at runtime?

Comment: What is problematic about `foo.hypotethical( new ArrayList<ChildBar>() )`?

Comment: You should pass `Class<T> clazz` as argument: `Collection<T> hypothetical( List<T> items, Class<T> clazz)`

Comment: I found 3 errors: 1) `dostuffWithItems` is undefined. 2) `hypothetical`, `hypotethical`, and `hypothetic` are not spelled the same. 3) Return type `Collection` cannot be assigned to `List`. --- Are these the _PROBLEMATIC_'s you have too? Because once I fix those 3, I have no compile errors.

Comment: @Louis that is an invocation of the problematic method with a type argument that is supposedly child type of T type argument. That it is not compiling is the problematic part.

Comment: @Luiggi I do not want another clazz argument. The runtime type of <T> could be obtained without the extra argument. However, I want a way for the compiler to automatically enforce that type List<T> of the hypothetical argument is equivalent to the class Foo<T> type parameter.

Comment: @Andreas, dostuffWithItems definition is simply not included for brevity.

Comment: Stephen Isienyi - please look at the code in my answer (which does compile) and tell us what you are doing differently.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This seems to be currently impossible in Java. 
`Foo<? extends ChildBar> foo = new Foo<ChildBar>( ChildBar.class );`
This leave foo with an ambiguous parametric type. It is obvious that ChildBar would become the true de facto parametric type. The call to the `foo.hypothetical()` method with the `List<ChildBar>` exposes this assumption to be untrue. Although `foo.hypothetical` only accepts a `List<>` argument containing elements of the foo parametric type, it still fails to recognize that the argument was a list of ChildBar objects.
For this use case, the object parametric type must be specified during foo declaration in order make it a part and parcel of the foo runtime reference.
`Foo<ChildBar> foo = new Foo<ChildBar>( ChildBar.class );`
All conforming `List<ChildBar>` arguments of the foo.hypothetical method will now correctly be accepted as carrying elements of the foo's declared parametric type.

Comment: *"This seems to be currently impossible in Java."* - And it >>should<< be.  If that was legal you could construct examples where the code was unsafe according to the compile-time generic typing model.

Comment: Are you saying that Java authors deliberately made it impossible because users can construct codes that would be unsafe according to the compile-time generic typing model? Would you care to provide possible examples of codes that would be unsafe according to the compile-time generic typing model as a result of making this feature possible?

Comment: @StephenIsienyi yes, the error message is raised because otherwise users could write, compile and run code that would fail with a type error at runtime.  After you told me that the terms "wildcard" and "capture" are not essential, I have no idea how I should explain this to you any further.

Comment: @Stephen Hermann, wildcard and capture are fundamentals to Java generics programming.

Comment: Wildcard and capture are not necessary to answer this question. Those are simply general basics of Java generic programming.

Answer (score 5):

I edited your code and added the missing stuff to make it compilable, and I can confirm that the only problematic parts are:

- The missing `dostuffWithItems` method.
- The typos with the `hypothetical` method name.
- Assigning a `Collection<ChildBar>` to a `List<ChildBar>`.

The first two are easy to fix.

The last one requires you to either change the change the API method, or change the code where you are calling it.  Neither of these is (IMO) problematic.  Furthermore, the

It is worth noting that you would get all of these errors if the types were non-generic.  You can't assign a `Collection` to a `List` without a typecast.

---

Here's my code for you to play with.  (Copy and paste into appropriately named files ...)

```
public class Bar {
}

public class ChildBar extends Bar {
}

import java.util.*;

public class Foo<T extends Bar> {
    private Class<T> _type;
    public Foo( Class<T> _type ) {
        this._type = _type;
    }
    public Collection<T> hypothetical( List<T> items ) { 
        return items;  // dummy implementation ...
    }
}

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Foo<ChildBar> foo = new Foo<ChildBar>( ChildBar.class );
       Collection<ChildBar> items = 
               foo.hypothetical( new ArrayList<ChildBar>() );
    }
}
```

Comment: Stephen C, thanks for putting my comment into an answer. Up-vote from me.

Comment: @Stephen C, Good for attempting to complete the code. The original code was simply a code snippet with just the sufficient information to convey the problem in the post. The missing items can be reasonably deduced. Please concentrate on addressing the **compiler error message:** ***the method hypothetical(List<capture#2-of ?>) in the type Foo<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (List<ChildBar>)***

Comment: There is no compilation error when I compile my version of the code.  None.  Not with Java7 or Java 8.  Please examine my code carefully, and explain how your code is different, so that we can answer your question.

Comment: Being that it works on your end, I suppose the error is coming from the Eclipse Mars JVM. I will clarify with the Eclipse team

Comment: @StephenC, I am yet to receive a response to [my enquiry](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=476155) from Eclipse team. I might have to use your IDE to test it out. Which IDE are you using? Thanks

Comment: Ah I found why we had the mismatch. My running code was indeed `Foo<? extends Bar> foo = new Foo<ChildBar>( ChildBar.class );` My apologies there

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't precisely explain why the snippet in the question (after edits) is rejected by the compiler.

We start from the observation that the snippet from @Stephen C's answer is accepted, while revision 8 of the question is rejected. The difference is: in the latter version the variable `foo` is declared with a wildcard-parameterized type `Foo<? extends ChildBar>`, while Stephen C had copied `Foo<ChildBar>` from an earlier revision (we all seem to agree that this is a suitable way to resolve the compile error).

To understand why this difference is crucial please see that with `Foo<? extends ChildBar> foo` this wildcard propagates as a capture into the signature for the invocation of `foo.hypothetical`, so this invocation is rendered as `hypothetical(List<capture#2-of ?>)`, meaning that the parameter has an unknown (upper-bounded) type parameter. `List<ChildBar>` is not compatible to that type, hence the compile error.

Also note that all mentions of "runtime" in this thread are inappropriate, all this is statically resolved at compile time. Perhaps you meant invocation type, or type of the actual argument, as opposed to the declared type (of the formal parameter). The actual runtime type is unknown to the compiler.

Comment: Your answer is still in support of the same premise described in the accepted answer. However, your answer is late on arrival and your wording is vitriolic. It is officious in that it did not add any new knowledge besides rewording the accepted answer and stating that java resolves its generic type parameters during compilation. You surely could make those points without the combative language.

Comment: Runtime references (along with their type parameters for generic types) are resolved during compilation. So the "runtime reference" mentioned in the accepted answer, in the scope of its usage, is perfectly legitimate.

Comment: @StephenIsienyi, to be specific: the situation cannot be explained in full without mentioning the concepts of wildcards and capture.

Comment: StephenIsienyi, I admit I got very confused by comments and answers relating to a questions that has undergone many edits afterwards. I edited my answer accordingly. I'm sure you get better answers on SO, when you paste the exact code which you have previously tested to show the behaviour in question. WRT the original question, the answer by @Stephen C was correct.

Comment: @StephenIsienyi - Also note that repeatedly changing your question is "bad form", especially if the changes amount to a complete rewrite that enirely changes the meaning.

Comment: @StephenC, there is absolutely no bad form here. The question was not changed. I updated the question, and I specifically notified you about it. Can you, in good conscience, say that you did not see my comment to you at 18:36 on 9/1/2016?

Comment: You should have left the original content there.  The fact that you commented is not relevant.  The problem is that by changing the question you rendered previous answers meaningless, largely nullifying the effort that various people made to help you.  If you wanted to be respectful of peoples' efforts, you should include the key parts of the original question in place, and acknowledged (permanently) in the question text that your sample code did not match what you were saying.

Comment: @Stephan Hermann, the question you answered today was lastly edited a couple of days ago. The concepts of wildcards and capture is a prerequisite topic that is outside the scope of the posed question. You are entitled to your perceived necessity to delve into them in your response.

Comment: @StephenIsienyi - As I said.  That is beside the point.  You can't expect someone who tried to help you one day (for free) to try to help you the next day (for free).

Comment: @StephenC, you are the only one who responded. That is why I commented to you. That comment is relevant because you saw it and through it, you were made aware of the edit so that you could update your answer if you wished. You did not respond. I continued to scratch my head for an additional day to figure out why that code was not compiling. In the end, I had to accept that there is no way in Java, to accomplish what I intended and why.